# How to pass interface to struct on golang

Tags: go

Here is a sample code, I want to call `interface function` throw a `struct`

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

type Person interface {
    sayHello()()
}

func sayHello()() {
    fmt.Printf("hello\n")
}

type Foo struct {
    num int
    person Person
}

var FooChan = make(chan *Foo, 200)

func say() () {
    for {
        select {
            case f := <-FooChan:
                f.person.sayHello() // runtime error here
                fmt.Printf("num %v\n", f.num)
        }
    }
}

func main()(){
    var foo Foo
    foo.num = 2
    FooChan <- &foo
    go say()
    time.Sleep(10*time.Second)
}
```

I want to call `sayHello()` throw `interface`, this `Person interface` may be defined in another file. I get `panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference` when I run it. How can I call `sayHello()`?

Comment: Why do you have two times ( )( )?

Comment: can you add your Foo struct to the question? my guess is, that you set the num field of your struct to '2' but never initialise any person of your foo type. so f.person is nil and you can't call a function on nil

Comment: @meaningqo They are all the codes

Answer (score -1, accepted):

From https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/interfaces-in-golang/:

> Go language interfaces are different from other languages. In Go
> language, the interface is a custom type that is used to specify a set
> of one or more method signatures and the interface is abstract, so you
> are not allowed to create an instance of the interface. But you are
> allowed to create a variable of an interface type and this variable
> can be assigned with a concrete type value that has the methods the
> interface requires. Or in other words, the interface is a collection
> of methods as well as it is a custom type.

So here if you want to make the channel generic for the types which implement the Person interface may be you want create different types like farmer, doctor and you just want to call this `say` method like

```golang
func say() {
    for {
        select {
        case f := <-FooChan:
            f.sayHello()
        }
    }
}
```

And you just pass the different person in the channel and will get the output of the person type's sayHello() method's output

An example is given below. May this will help to clear you concept with golang's interface:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

type Person interface {
    sayHello()
}

func(f *Farmer) sayHello() {
    fmt.Printf("hello from farmer\n")
    fmt.Printf("num %d\n", f.num)
}

type Farmer struct {
    num int
    Person
}

type Doctor struct {
    num int
    Person
}

func(f *Doctor) sayHello() {
    fmt.Printf("hello from doctor\n")
    fmt.Printf("num %d\n", f.num)
}

var FooChan = make(chan Person, 200)

func say() {
    for {
        select {
        case f := <-FooChan:
            f.sayHello()
        }
    }
}

func main(){
    foo := &Farmer{
        num:    2,
    }

    FooChan <- foo
    go say()

    foo2 := &Doctor{
        num: 1,
    }
    FooChan <- foo2

    time.Sleep(10*time.Second)
}
```

Comment: This answer was plagiarized from https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/interfaces-in-golang/

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a struct that implements the interface Person.

```
type IImplementPersonMethod struct {}


func (IImplementPersonMethod) sayHello()() {
    fmt.Printf("hello\n")
}
```

Then inside the Foo, you pass this struct, so your code should be :
(i removed the ()() on main function, since main is func dont need it and it can result on a warning)

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

type Person interface {
    sayHello()()
}

type IImplementPersonMethod struct {}


func (IImplementPersonMethod) sayHello()() {
    fmt.Printf("hello\n")
}

type Foo struct {
    num int
    person Person
}

var FooChan = make(chan *Foo, 200)

func say() () {
    for {
        select {
            case f := <-FooChan:
                f.person.sayHello() // runtime error here
                fmt.Printf("num %v\n", f.num)
        }
    }
}

func main(){
    var foo Foo
    foo.num = 2
    foo.person=IImplementPersonMethod{}
    FooChan <- &foo
    go say()
    time.Sleep(10*time.Second)
}
```